# Solve for the missing vector in a cross product

Tags: vectors, cross-product

How can I answer this question?

Solve for all vectors $A$ so that $( 1, 2, 1) \times A  = (3, 1, -5)$.

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication). And think!

Comment: Better to add your attempt.

Comment: I've removed the irrelevant calculus tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=\left(\begin{array}{c}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{array}\right)$ so$$\left(\begin{array}{c}
3\\
1\\
-5
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
2\\
1
\end{array}\right)\times\left(\begin{array}{c}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
2c-b\\
a-c\\
b-2a
\end{array}\right),$$which has general solution $a=1+c,\,b=2a-5=-3+2c$, i.e.$$A=\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
-3\\
0
\end{array}\right)+c\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
2\\
1
\end{array}\right).$$

Comment: Hi J.G., if I find the nullspace of the matrix
$\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & -1 & 2 \\
    1 & 0 & -1 \\
    -2 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$

 I get $c \times \begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    2 \\
    1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$

Is this somehow related to the solution? where does the 
 $\begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    -3 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$ vector come from?  Thanks.

Comment: @PcumP_Ravenclaw I got it from seeking a $c=0$ solution so I could write $a,\,b$ in terms of $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Write the cross product using the matrix notation.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Matrix_notation

Solve the system you obtain!

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to solve simultaneous equation (either by substitution or elimination) you can find the components of the vector A after applying the definition of the cross product of the two vectors.

$ $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    i & j & k \\
    1 & 2 & 1 \\
    a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$ $

$(2\times a_3 -  a_2) \hat i - (a_3 - a_1)\hat j + (a_2 - 2 \times a_1)\hat k = (3) \hat i + (1)\hat j - (5)\hat k $

compare/equate the components in the above equations.

from equation 1 $a_3 = \frac{3 + a_2}{2} $

substitute this into 2nd equation, $ a_3 = a_1 - 1$

$\frac{3 + a_2}{2} = a_1 - 1$

solve the above equation with the third equation $ a_2 - 2\times a_1 = -5$ as simultaneous equations in two variables and you will encounter the problem of

$2a_1 - 2 = 2a_1 - 2$ so that there is no solution. This is the same for $a_2$ and $a_1$

I could write the above system of linear equations in matrix form as

$ $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & -1 & 2 \\
    1 & 0 & -1 \\
    -2 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$ $ $ $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a_1 \\
    a_2 \\
    a_3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$ $ $=$ $ $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    3 \\
    1 \\
    -5 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$ $

If I try to invert the 3x3 matrix on the left I find that it is singular (non-invertible) which suggests that there is no vector $A$ that can satisfy this linear system of equations. The vector $<3,1,-5>$ is outside the column space of the matrix so it cannot be reached.

No such vector A exists.

Comment: You've miscalculated; see my answer.